# Auth protect a Wordpress site except one page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I protected an entire Wordpress site with an .htaccess in the /var/www/html direction containing the following regular authentication:

```
AuthName "Restricted Admin-Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

However, now my boss asks me to unprotect just one page of the Wordpress site (specifically /subscription):

- When we access www.site.com/subscription : no authentication is asked
- When we access the rest of www.site.com : an authentication is asked

So I added the following as an exclusion:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(subscription/)$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(subscription)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

The problem though, is that for this exclusion to work, the subscription/ directory must exist "physically" on the server.

But it is a **Wordpress page, generated automatically following index.php contained in the Wordpress database**.

Therefore, the **exclusion does not work** and I'm asked an authentication when accessing this page.

I've looked for hours and tried to modify tons of things (even creating a subscription2/ directory pointing to subscription), but nothing worked.

Please can you help?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use .htaccess? Could you do something at the server config level? A <Location "/subscription"> with the allow rules in it would probably solve this.

Comment: Actually looking again, your Order is probably killing you. Try:
```Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=allow```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it @BenjaminClose, but now it gives me a 403 Forbidden on all the site and Authentication remaining on /subscription.